# Stripe PaymentIntent missing payment method

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to take payments, but on occasion the following error is logged:

> Secure customer authentication failed. You cannot confirm this
> PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either
> update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it
> again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method.

The following JS is used to process, which works 90% of the time. I can't see why on occasion the PaymentIntent would be missing the payment method.

```
var card = elements.create('card', {
    hidePostalCode: false
});

card.mount('#card-element');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
    }
});
    
var cardButton = document.getElementById("checkout_complete");

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var card_name = document.getElementById('card_name').value;

    stripe.createPaymentMethod("card", card, {
        billing_details: {
            name: card_name
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {                    
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", "payment-method-id");
            input.setAttribute("value", result.paymentMethod.id);
            document.getElementById("checkout_payment_form").appendChild(input);
            document.getElementById("checkout_payment_form").submit(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The main error here is “Secure customer authentication failed.”. For some of the card payments, issuer banks require Strong Customer Authentication (SCA), like 3DSecure. If you follow the [recommended Stripe integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements), card authentication will be handled for you.

However, I see that you are confirming the payment on the backend, in which case you will have to handle SCA yourself. [Here’s a guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously?platform=web#web-handle-next-actions) you can follow to manually trigger card authentication.

If this is not what is happening, please share more detail about the exact request that leads to this error.